# Modulus operator in mysql with negative numbers?

Tags: mysql, modulus

Column negative balance has a variety of **negative** numbers that include decimals.  I am trying to return only values that are factors of .5.

Can you help me rework these queries to return some rows of data?

1.

```
Set @K = -0.50;
select * from tbl_accounts where endingbalance % @K = 0;
```

2.

```
select * from tbl_accounts where endingbalance % -.5 = 0;
```

Comment: What is there in `endingbalance` and what is your expected output? Give some sample rows.

Answer (score 1):

You have not provided any sample data, so if your `endingbalance` has any value which ends in `.50` or `.00`, you will get output.

****<kbd>[Rexter Sample](http://rextester.com/BNSD70614)</kbd>****

```
set @K = -0.50;
select endingbalance % @K from 
(select -20.50 as endingbalance union all
 select -20.43                  union all
 select -20.75
) t;
```

Output

```
endingbalance % @K
------------------------------
0,0000000000000000000000000000
-0,4300000000000000000000000000
-0,2500000000000000000000000000
```

So if you move the mod condition to `where` clause, you will get rows ending in `.00` or 0.50`

```
set @K = -0.50;
select * from 
(select -20.50 as endingbalance union all
 select -20.43                  union all
 select -20.75
) t
where endingbalance % @K =0
```

Output

```
endingbalance
--------------------------
-20,50
```

Comment: That is exactly what Im looking for.  Sadly... my queries arent returning any rows.  I thought it perhaps has something to do with negative symbol within the table.

Comment: No. Negative symbol doesn't have anything to do with it. Try running `endingbalance % @K` in select clause to see if you have any values ending at .50 or .00

Comment: Could you explain how I would structure that statement within my select clause?

Comment: `select endingbalance ,endingbalance % -0.5 from your_table limit 5`. Also try `select endingbalance ,endingbalance % -0.5 from your_table where endingbalance % -0.5 = 0 limit 5`